# Running time question

Tags: runtime-analysis

If I have two kinds of LinkedList $A$ and $B$.

> $A$ is a move to front one which means:
> >>> lst1 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
> >>> lst1.**contain**(7)
> True
> >>> lst1.to_list
> 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9
> $B$ is a swap list, which means:
> >>> lst2 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
> >>> lst2.**contain**(7)
> True
> >>> lst2.to_list
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9

I want to find a searching sequence such that the running time of $B$ is faster than $A$. I mean the Theta of them would be different. The length of lst1 and lst2 are both $n$. We search $m$ times and can search different elements for different times.

Comment: (3, 1, 2?) Please state in your question: Do you look for one example, for a description of some/all sequences where the *sum of the positions of the keys searched* is smaller for *swap with predecessor*, or something else, entirely?

Answer (score 1):

The move-to-front heuristic is 4-competitive in the model where swapping adjacent elements costs one unit. This means that if the optimal strategy has cost $N$, then move-to-front has cost at most $4N$. In particular, if a swap list has cost $N$ on some searching sequence, then move-to-front will have cost at most $4N$.

See for example [MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-design-and-analysis-of-algorithms-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT6_046JS12_lec12.pdf) or [Princeton Slides](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr11/cos423/Lectures/MTFListUpdating.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The sequence `7, 1` will be ever so slightly faster for $B$ than for $A$, however, both structures have running time $O(n)$ for checking membership and are therefore not particularly suited if this is the main point of the data structure.

The former list is reminiscent of a Least Recently Used (LRU) cache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need different Big Theta (Big O, whatever). So we cannot use the sequence you raised. But thanks all the same